# Saving users name input

Tags: java, variables

Doing homework to average grades, and I want to store the users name. It is working good so far, if they press 1 it asks for name, press 2 it quits, press 3 it mentions an error and exits.

BUT how can I store the users name? Is it boolean or string?

I saved the variable as:                            String name;
and the input line that reads from the scanner is:  name = dylan.nextString();

I can't seem to find how to save the users input

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Assignment3
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    { 
        Scanner dylan = new Scanner( System.in );

        double homework;
        double quiz;
        double test;
        int choice;
        String name; <------ Here

        System.out.println( "Enter 1 or 2: \n 1 - Average grades \n 2 - Quit" ); 
        choice = dylan.nextInt();

        if ( choice == 1 ) 
        {   
            System.out.println( "What is your name?" );

            name = dylan.nextString();   <----- Here
        }


        if ( choice == 2 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Exiting program." );
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println( "Invalid response, exiting program." )  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a `List` or `Array` of `names`.

Comment: If u press 3 Invalid response, exiting program. will be the output.What error u receive ??

Comment: where do you want to save users input? In a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `nextString()` which doesn't exist for the `Scanner` class, use [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

So like this:

```
name = dylan.nextLine();
```

And yes, a name is stored as a `String`

A [`boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) has only two values: `true` or `false`

---

Also change this:

```
if ( choice == 2 )
```

to

```
else if ( choice == 2 )
```

The reason is because as your code was, it would check if `choice == 1`, which may be true, and then check if `choice == 2`, even if `choice == 1` already because it there wasn't an *else* if.

And then obviously because if `choice == 1` then it can't also be `choice == 2` so it would go into the `else` block and execute that code, as well as the block for `choice == 1`

Comment: Thanks! Now that I have it fixed, when I press 1 it prints out this: What is your name? Invalid response, exiting program. How can I prevent it from executing the Else line and only executing the first if line from by pressing 1

Comment: @Darkcobra94 Check my updated answer. Please accept it if it works for you.

Comment: I was doing my homework completely wrong, I wasn't supposed to ask what Grades they wanted to average, BUT instead tell them that they are going to be averaging homework grades first, then quiz grades, then test grades.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.project.stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner dylan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double homework;
        double quiz;
        double test;
        int choice;
        String name;
        // Note the changes
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Enter 1 or 2: \n 1 - Average grades \n 2 - Quit");
        choice = dylan.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1) {

            System.out.println("What is your name?");
            name = dylan.next();
            //This list will have the name of the user. 
            names.add(name);
            System.out.println("Your Name--"+name);
            //System.out.println("Stored List--"+names);
        }

        else if (choice == 2) {

            System.out.println("Exiting program.");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid response, exiting program.");
        }

        // close the Scanner object
        dylan.close();
    }
}
```

Find the code for the same. I have made some changes to it. 
User name is a string which is stored in 'name'. Another List 'names', holds the same too.
Try it. It should work fine. 
Though I have edited this for you, go for switch case instead of if-else in such cases. Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any loops, so I will consider that you just need to store a single name

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3

{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner dylan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double homework;
        double quiz;
        double test;
        int choice;
        String name = "";// Here

        System.out.println("Enter 1 or 2: \n 1 - Average grades \n 2 - Quit");
        choice = dylan.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("What is your name?");
            name = dylan.next(); // Here
        }

        else if (choice == 2) {

            System.out.println("Exiting program.");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid response, exiting program.");
        }

        System.out.println("Thank You! The name entered is :" + name);

    }

}
```